# Does Beckett have a philosophy of life, in Worstward Ho?

Tags: existentialism

Does Beckett have a philosophy of life, in Worstward Ho? It contains the famous line "Ever failed. No matter. Try again. Fail again. Fail better.". At face value, it suggests taking comfort in failure.

Answer (score 0):

You forge your own meanings heroically amongst the existential dread, and then, then they become as natural, as they are continuously heroic.

I would highly recommend reading this book:

> Foster Paul. 1989. Beckett and Zen : A Study of Dilemma in the Novels
> of Samuel Beckett. London: Boston MA USA : Wisdom Publications.

Comment: i'm not sure i believe you have read it, but the answer is fine